# Add text to Rich Textbox in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, richtextbox

I am working on a GUI for our office and I have run across an issue, the GUI works wonderfully if you don't have to output text to the GUI. I currently have a Rich Textbox to take the output and display it but it isn't displaying.

```
$WPFbtnDisk.Add_Click({
start-sleep -Milliseconds 840
write-host "Disk Clicked"
$WPFRichtextbox =gwmi win32_service -ComputerName ($WPFtxtServerName.Text) | sort DisplayName | select-object     SystemName,DisplayName,StartMode,State,PathName | Out-String
})
```

This is the code that I have right now that according to what I read should load the box but it doesn't, if I change it to just a normal textbox it outputs but it just doesn't have any formatting so it is next to impossible to read.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't assign text directly to a RichtextBox object like that. Use `$WPFRichtextbox.AppendText($(gwmi win32_service ...))`

Comment: Wow I completely messed that up, that worked like a charm, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` control does not have a `Text` field like a normal textbox, but a [`Document`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) property which contains a reference to a [`FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) that makes up the contents of the `RichTextBox`.

In lieu of creating and maintaining a `FlowDocument`, you can add text to the existing empty document with the `RichTextBox.AppendText()` method:

```
$WmiOutputTable = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $WPFtxtServerName.Text |Select-Object SystemName,DisplayName,StartMode,State,PathName |Sort-Object DisplayName |Out-String
$WPFRichtextbox.AppendText($WmiOutputTable)
```